# overriden methods in android studio show ambigious parameters name

Tags: android, kotlin

```
override fun onQueryPurchasesResponse(
    p0: BillingResult,
    p1: MutableList<Purchase>
)
```

Android Studio show's ambiguous parameters name in overridden methods. Can anyone guide me how to resolve it.

I downloaded sources for every SDK platform, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio (or one of its components) uses the names of the values it finds in the source code to populate these names when generating overrides. In this case the source code has been obfuscated and so there's nothing for it to use.

To quickly refactor to more sensible names you can use the keyboard shortcut `shift+F6` to get suggestions based on the variables' type.